# Android pdf maker code error

Tags: java, android, android-layout, pdf, bitmap

I'm trying to take a screenshot of my Android activity (bitmap) and then making a PDF file out of it. I used the itextpdf library. Here's what I have:

```
public void onSaveDataClicked(View reportsLayout){
    //take screen shot
    Bitmap screen; View v1 = reportsLayout.getRootView();
    v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    screen = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
    v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

    try {
        Document  document = new Document();

        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(file));
        document.open();
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        screen.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
        byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
        addImage(document,byteArray);
        document.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

    private static void addImage(Document document,byte[] byteArray) {
    Image image = null;
    try {
        image = Image.getInstance(byteArray);
    } catch (BadElementException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // image.scaleAbsolute(150f, 150f);
    try {
        document.add(image);
    } catch (DocumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

When I try to run I get the errors: "Image cannot be converted to Element" and "cannot find symbol method getInstance(byte[])"

A lot of the code I found online through a tutorial on how to achieve this. I'm kind of unfamiliar with this sort of thing. Any help and ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: this may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14811618/add-image-to-a-pdf-using-itext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `import com.itextpdf.text.Image;`and remove the default Android one.